# how to know db detail in hosting

Tags: database, wordpress, ftp

How to know database name password. I want to install `autoliker` `script` but there was error like

```
Password (yes)
```

And when I install `WordPress` so asking for

```
DB_NAME();

DATABASE_PASSWORD ();
```

please tell me how to know database name , password , user etc

Answer (score 0):

Ask your hosting provider. They will be able to help you

Comment: They can't reply me I buy since  2 or 3 month ago this was cheap host